# Django - Use signals to refresh another model's fields

Tags: python, django

I have two models, one of which uses data from the other model to populate its own fields. The issue is that when the first model is updated, the second model does not also update its own fields. I have to go in and actually edit/save the 2nd model for its fields to update.

Something like this:

models.py:

```
class ModelA(models.ModelForm)
    ...

class ModelB(models.ModelForm)
    count_number_of_model_A = models.IntegerField
    def save(self)
         self.count_number_of_model_A = ModelA.objects.all().count()
         super(ModelB, self).save()
```

(this is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do)

Now I want the field "count_number_of_model_A" in ModelB to update every time ModelA is altered. Right now, it only refreshes if I actually modify+save ModelB.

I think the answer is to use signals (maybe?). I'm trying to set up a signal so that ModelB updates whenever a new object is created in ModelA. I have the following:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=ModelA)
def update_sends(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created', False):
         #some code here to refresh ModelB??
```

The signal is functioning properly, as if I put in something like ModelB.objects.filter(some filter).update(some field), those changes are reflected when I go in and create a new ModelA object. But the whole model itself does not update, and the field in question that I'm after ("count_number_of_model_A") does not refresh.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
for model_b in ModelB.objects.filter(<some_filter>):
    model_b.save()
```

But you should be aware that this pulls all (filtered) objects to Django, there do something with them and saves them back to the database. This is much slower than using [query expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/). You will have a little bit more work to set it up, but it will run much faster - especially when database grows.

Comment: This worked great! Thanks! My DB is fairly small, so I'm not too worried about it slowing down, but I'll look into trying to switch it over. Thanks for your help!